# How to count bits in cache (direct & 4-way)

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Let's say, I have a cache with:

- 2^32 bytes of memory
- 2048 blocks (of 16 bytes each)

Now I'm trying to figure out how much bits each field will contain.

Direct mapped:

One block is 16 bytes (16 * 8 = 128 bits). The block also contains 1 dirty bit and 1 valid bit. I know that since there are 2048 (=2^11) blocks, and the whole block contains 16 bytes (=2^4) the tag-field will be 4 + 11 + 1 (valid) + 1 (dirty) = 17 bits. So the whole size of 1 block will be 17 + 128 bits. Is this right?

And if so, where do I need the given 2^32 bytes of memory, and what is the difference with the direct-mapped cache in comparison to counting the 4-way-set-associative cache fields?

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is easier to look at addresses :

- address range : A[31:0]
- block address : A[3:0]
- cache line index : A[14:4] : 2048 = 11bits

Each tag contains :

- addresses A[31:15] : 17bits
- valid bit
- dirty bit, if it is a write-back cache

So 18bits (write-thu) or 19bits (write-back) per tag.

128+18 per block (or 128+19),
2048*(128+18) bits for the whole cache. (excluding EDC, sub-blocking...)

**The tags contains the part of the address bits not indexed by the cache (not the contrary).**

Way associative caches need replicating both tags and data. Additional bits are also needed in that case for the replacement information (LRU, PLRU...) : Selecting which cache way should be replaced when a cache miss occurs.

Comment: Thanks!!! I only can't seem to figure out how to calculate it for the 4-way. On wikipedia it says I have to divide the number of blocks by 4 (4-way). 2048 / 4 = 512 (=2^9). So 32 - 9 - 3 = 20 bits (21 bits with wb), for the tag field?

Comment: Yes, 20 bits for 4-ways set-asssociative, if the size of the cache remains the same (2048 lines). If you want to store history bits in tags, a true LRU history for 4 ways can be stored in 5 bits (there are 24 possible combinations), so add 2 bits per tag. Alternatively, a less efficient random replacement algorithm can be used, it does not need additional tag bits.